# How to parse json value that is stored in an array and store selected value in array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I read json values from a text and store it in array using this code.

```
string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\\tweets.txt");
```

I need to extract certain fields from this array containing Json.
My Json is of this type:

```
{"Name":"John","Id":"45","Time":"11 pm"}
 {"Name":"Pear","Id":"34","Time":"3 pm"}
```

I want to extract each "Name" in one array and each "Id" in one array, something like this.

```
string[] Name= null;
string[] Id= null;
for (var i = 0; i < allLines[i].length; i++) 
{
Name = allLines[i].Name; 
Id   = allLines[i].Id;
}
```

I tried another way using json parsing as well. I can obtain one row at one time json deserialized this way. But then confused how to obtain the selected fields.

```
 StreamReader streamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("D:\\tweets.txt");
        string lineContent = streamReader.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            if (lineContent != null)
            {
                var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(lineContent);

            }
            lineContent = streamReader.ReadLine();

        }
        while (streamReader.Peek() != -1);
        streamReader.Close();
```

Please help.

Comment: You're looking for a JSON parser.  Except that your JSON doesn't actually make any sense.

Comment: Your JSON represents an object with duplicated property names.  Are you *sure* that is what you have?  The [JSON rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7158) states *The names within an object SHOULD be unique.*

Comment: I have edited my post, sorry for the mistake. please review again

Answer (score 0):

This example uses the NewtonSoft Json library to deserialize your Json into an object.  Then, linq is used to pull out the lists that you are interested in.

I have written this example as a Console Application in Visual Studio.  You will need to create a new Console Application, then copy this code into it.

Also, to use the NewtonSoft library in your new Console Application, you will need to load it from NuGet.  To do this in VisualStudio, you will need to

1. Right-click on the project name
2. Click on Manage NuGet Packages...
3. In the search box on the top right, enter "newtonsoft" (without the quotes)
4. Newtonsoft.Json should show up in the list.  Click it and press the Install button.  This will load the binary and set up the references in your project.  After that, you can use the sample code shown in this example.

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       TestParseJson();
       Console.WriteLine();
       Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to End");
       Console.ReadLine();  // Wait for input so we can see our output text
   }

   // 1 - Construct an object used for deserialization.  You will need to make this class match the format of the records in your json text file.
   public class User
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public DateTime Time { get; set; }
   }

   // 2 - Simulate Json creation and then use the NewtonSoft library to deserialize.  You will need to just extract from the DeserializeObject line down
   public static void TestParseJson()
   {
       // Read list of json objects from file, one line at a time.  The json in the test file users.json is in this format:
       // {"Name":"John","Id":45,"Time":"2015-11-05T19:18:02.0324468Z"}
       // {"Name":"Pear","Id":34,"Time":"2015-11-06T19:18:02.0329474Z"}
       var jsonLines = File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\users.json");
       var deserializedUsers = jsonLines.Select(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>).ToList();

       // Use Linq to project the list of deserializedUsers into the lists that you want
       var names = deserializedUsers.Select(user => user.Name);
       var ids = deserializedUsers.Select(user => user.Id);

       // Output list of names and ids for debugging purposes
       Console.WriteLine("");
       Console.WriteLine("   Names:");
       foreach (var name in names)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("      " + name);
       }

       Console.WriteLine("   Ids:");
       foreach (var id in ids)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("      " + id);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I read json data from a text file, so cannot directly add users like     users.Add(new User() { Id = 45, Name = "John", Time = DateTime.UtcNow }); What should I do?

Comment: I modified the example to read the json data from a text file.  To make this work, you will need to create a class similar to the User class in the above example.  Your class will need to match the format of the json objects in your file.  You will simply need to create a class that has property names and types that match those in your input json text file.  This will then deserialize as you would expect.  +1?

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TwitterProject.Models.TweetModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: Modified the example above to read in lines that represent a single json object one line at a time. The code then uses LINQ's Select to project the list of lines from the file into json objects. The prior example would have worked had your file contained json in the form of an array, with [ ] around the lines representing your objects. Since your file doesn't have an array of json objects, but rather single objects, this example should work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse JSON, you can download it as a NuGet package. 
It has some great documentation about querying JSON [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Querying your JSON with LINQ would look something like:

`JObject json = JObject.Parse(json);
var name = from p in json 
    select (string)p["Name"];`

Comment: StreamReader streamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("D:\\tweets.txt");
            string lineContent = streamReader.ReadLine();
            do
            {
                if (lineContent != null)
                {
                    JObject json = JObject.Parse(lineContent);
                    var name = from p in json
                              select (string)p["Name"];
                }
                lineContent = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
            while (streamReader.Peek() != -1);
            streamReader.Close();

Comment: I used the above code and get error as "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' select not found. Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'p'

Comment: Ok. If you change your JSON to an array like this: [
    {
        "Name": "John",
        "Id": "45",
        "Time": "11 pm"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Pear",
        "Id": "34",
        "Time": "3 pm"
    }
]

Comment: You could then use JArray to parse the json: string json = File.ReadAllText(@"tweets.json");
            JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);

            foreach (var token in jsonArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(token["Name"]);
            }

Comment: Thanks but I cannot make that change to the Json file, any other Idea please.

Comment: Bur your current json is invalid. Try and run it against a [validator](http://jsonlint.com/) and it will return a parser error

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON does not actually represent an array, but rather a series of individual objects back-to-back.  To be considered a valid JSON array, the objects would need to be enclosed in square brackets and separated by commas (see [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)).  Regardless, it is still possible to read and parse this non-standard JSON using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).  The [`JsonTextReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) class has a special `SupportMultipleContent` setting that is designed to cope with this situation.  You can process your file using the following code:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
List<string> ids = new List<string>();

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:\\tweets.txt"))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            names.Add((string)jo["Name"]);
            ids.Add((string)jo["Id"]);
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Names: " + string.Join(", ", names));
Console.WriteLine("Ids: " + string.Join(", ", ids));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tYVLLr